# All of bash history No such file or directory error on directories with spaces

Tags: bash

I have been attempting to implement the functionality described in the blog article "[All of bash history revisited](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2012/03/07-all-bash-history-revisited-load-time-solved-plus-directory-history)". Basically what the scripts enable you to do is keep all of your bash history forever and across multiple sessions.

Someone has kindly made all of the code [easily accessible on Github](https://github.com/oktools/all-bash-history).

However whenever I use a directory with spaces:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
mkdir "dir with spaces"
cd dir\ with\ spaces/
```

the next time I log in I get an errors like the following:

```
-bash: pushd: /Users/jack/Desktop/dir: No such file or directory
-bash: pushd: with: No such file or directory
-bash: pushd: spaces: No such file or directory
```

The only reference that I understood didn't seem to be causing the problem:

```
# Now change to the new dir and add to the top of the stack
pushd "${the_new_dir}" > /dev/null
```

I'm hoping some bash scripting expert can point out the error in the code so I can patch it.

Comment: Not sure, but try `the_new_dir="$1"` instead of `the_new_dir=$1`.

Comment: @nneonneo quoting is not needed on an expansion on the right side of an assignment. Word splitting does not occur there.

Comment: Is it possible there's something else in your .bashrc that's choking on the directory name?

Answer (score 4):

This was the culprit:

```
for x in `hd 20` `pwd`; do cd_func $x ; done
```

Replace with:

```
( hd 20; pwd ) | while read x; do cd_func "$x"; done
```

Pull request issued at github repo.